# position Corner stamp in jquery masonry to the left

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Anyone know how I could alter the corner stamp in jquery masonry to show on the left side instead of the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: simply make the "corner stamp element" the first .masonry-brick element. The first, meaning the topmost and leftmost, element will always remain in that position, unless you prepend elements.